# How to pause dispatcherTimer

Tags: c#, timer, dispatcher

Hello, I am working on my first project in school, which is a simple Brick-Breaker game.
I've got a problem which occours when I click on the "Pause" button, the timer stops, but when I click on the "Continue" Button, the timer continues as if the the game was never paused.
I've extensivly searched for an answer but was not able to find one which was possible for me to intergrate into my program (I've only been programming for 2 months.)

My program is almost ready, and it's all divided into classes and methods, therefore it'll be a bit harder for me to paste exactly the important lines, but I'll give it a try anyways.

I had tried several solutions, like creating a stopwatch and then declaring the timer as

_time.Text = (duration.TotalSeconds - pausingTimer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString

But unfortunetly that way of thinking got me nowhere so far. These are the lines which affect the pause and continue features of the game.:

```
  //data members (of Game Manager class)
private DispatcherTimer gamingLoopTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
 private DateTime _startTime;
 private TimeSpan _timeSpan;
 private Stopwatch pausingTimer = new Stopwatch();

  //ct'or
_timeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
_difficultyTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 800);

 public void StartGame()
    {
        gamingLoopTimer.Interval = _timeSpan;
        gamingLoopTimer.Tick += GamingLoopHandler;
        gamingLoopTimer.Start();

        increasingDifficultyTimer.Interval = _difficultyTimeSpan;
        increasingDifficultyTimer.Tick += IncreasingDifficulty;
        increasingDifficultyTimer.Start();


        _startTime = DateTime.Now;

 private void GamingLoopHandler(object sender, object e)
    {
        UpdateGameState();
        DrawState();
    }

 private void DrawState()
    {
        TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Now - _startTime;  
        _time.Text = (duration.TotalSeconds - pausingTimer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString

public void StopButton()
    {
        pausingTimer.Start();
        gamingLoopTimer.Stop();
        increasingDifficultyTimer.Stop();           
        _hasStopped = true;

        PromptGameStop();
    }

  private void ContinueToPlay(IUICommand command)
    {
        pausingTimer.Stop();
        pausingTimer.Reset();
        gamingLoopTimer.Start();
        increasingDifficultyTimer.Start();
        _hasStopped = false;
    }
```

note: I've tried to copy only the important code for the question, I hope I didn't delete anything important for the understanding of the answerers.

As stated above, the timer stops, but then continues as if it never stopped.

For example, should I press the "Pause" button at the 5-second mark, and click "Continue" after 15 seconds, the timer will continue from 20.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: DateTime.Now is not paused.  Recalculate `_start` when you resume.

Comment: Instead of computing the time elapsed since your start time, simply use a [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) which you can [Stop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.stop(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.start(v=vs.110).aspx) however often you want.  It has an [Elapsed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx) property you can use to get the time elapsed.

Comment: Thanks Idle-Mind! it worked perfectly :)